# OpenCL casting to convert float4 components into uchars

Tags: casting, opencl, rgb

I have an OpenCL program that calculates pixel RGB values.  Declaration as follows.

```
__kernel void pixel_kernel( __global uchar* r,
                        __global uchar* g,
                        __global uchar* b, 
                        __global uchar* a,
                        __global int* width,
                        __global int* height)
```

During the program a float4 col variable is created and calculated.  So I want to extract the RGB components and return them as the r g b and a uchar types.

At the end of the code I have

```
r[x]=255;
g[x]=0;
b[x]=0;
```

Which happily compiles and the returned color is red.

If I try and convert the float4 values into RGB I cannot seem to work out how to cast them.  For example the following results in a compilation error and the cl does not run

```
r[x]=(uchar)(col[0]*255);
g[x]=(uchar)(col[1]*255);
b[x]=(uchar)(col[2]*255);
```

What am I missing?  How should this cast be declared so it correctly converts the float RGB components into uchar values between 0 and 255?

Must be a simple fix, but I have tried all permutations of casting I can think of and none of them seem to want to work.  Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCL `float4` data type contains 4 `float`. To address these components, you can use either `.x`, `.y`, `.z`, `.w` or `.s0`, `.s1`, `.s2`, `.s3`:

```c
float4 col = (float4)(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f);
r[x]=(uchar)(col.s0*255);
g[x]=(uchar)(col.s1*255);
b[x]=(uchar)(col.s2*255);
a[x]=(uchar)(col.s3*255);
```

`float4 col;` is not the same as a 4-vector `float col[4];`, but more like a C99 struct; this is why addressing like `col[0]` does not work with `float4`. See also the [OpenCL 1.2 Reference Card](https://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-1-2-quick-reference-card.pdf) page 3.